# too many values to unpack (expected 2) - Django SQL exception

Tags: python, django

I am writing basic sign up view code with the Django framework.

I have the following code:

```
def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        firstname = request.POST.get("firstname")
        lastname = request.POST.get("lastname")

        userObj = User.objects.filter(username)
        if userObj.exists():
            return HttpResponse("username already exists")
        emailObj = User.objects.filter(email)
        if emailObj.exists():
            return HttpResponse("email already exists")
        newUser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password, first_name=firstname, last_name=lastname)
        if newUser is not Null:
            newUser.save()
            # render main menu page
            return HttpResponse("user successfully registered")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("error creating newUser")
```

The failure is because of the lines  `userObj = User.objects.filter(username)` and  `emailObj = User.objects.filter(email)`

Here is part of the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "G:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "G:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "G:\Programming\project3\orders\views.py", line 21, in register
    userObj = User.objects.filter(username)
  File "G:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "G:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1350, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "G:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "G:\Program Files\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1247, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr

Exception Type: ValueError at /register
Exception Value: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

What can be done to avoid this, because I am doing only the basic Django sign up as required by documentation itself.. ?

Answer (score 2):

`User.objects.filter(username)` makes no sense, you have to use something like `User.objects.filter(username=username)`